# Linq query for two tables using SUM and Group By

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables

Replies

```
|ReplyID     |ReplyText | QuestionID | CreatedOn  |
|1           |xxxxxx    |1           | 01/01/2016 |
|2           |yyyyyy    |2           | 02/01/2016 |
|3           |zzzzzz    |3           | 03/01/2015 |
```

and Votes

```
|ReplyID     |VoteValue |UserId   |
|1           |1         |1        |
|1           |1         |2        |
|2           |-1        |3        |
|3           |1         |4        |
```

I m trying to join two tables on ReplyIds against id value which I m getting as a controller parameter.

This is the linq query I m using:

```
Replies = from r in db.Replies
          join v in db.Votes on r.ReplyID equals v.ReplyId
          where r.QuestionId == id
          orderby r.CreatedOn descending
          group v by v.ReplyId into g
          select g.Key
```

where Replies is

```
public IGrouping<Reply, Vote> Replies { get; set; }
```

I m having this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to System.Linq.IGrouping'

I m unable to proceed from here. I need to Sum(VoteValues) in Votes table and join it with Replies table to get all column values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to actually execute the query. Othewise, you won't get back actual results (IGrouping), but rather the definition for the query *to be executed* (IQueryable). Try calling ToList on your query before storing it into your Replies property.

Comment: Definitely the query result is not `IGrouping<Reply, Vote>`.

Comment: 'g' is a collection object but you are selecting g.key which is a singleton.   Change g.key to just g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx) instead:

```
var result= from r in db.Replies
            join v in db.Votes on r.ReplyID equals v.ReplyId into votes
            where r.QuestionId == id
            orderby r.CreatedOn descending
            select new {Reply=r, Votes=votes.Sum(v=>v.VoteValue)};
```

According what you describe you need to get all columns from `Reply` and the sum of all votes. This way you can project your query using an anonymous to save the `Reply` instance and the sum that you need. Now, maybe you need to save the projection in a known type because you need to pass the result of this query to a controller. In that case I suggest create a custom class (also known as DTO):

```
public class ReplySum
{ 
  public Reply Reply {get;set;}
  public int Votes{get;set;}
}
```

And now you can project your query this way:

```
IQueryable<ReplySum> query =from r in db.Replies
                            join v in db.Votes on r.ReplyID equals v.ReplyId into votes
                            where r.QuestionId == id
                            orderby r.CreatedOn descending
                            select new ReplySum{Reply=r, Votes=votes.Sum(v=>v.VoteValue)};
```

Another thing you need to consider is materialize your query before pass the result to your view:

```
var result=query.ToList();//Or ToArray
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. A perfect answer !

Answer (score 1):

Your query can be simpler by using lambda expression:

```
var result = db.Replies.Select(i => new
                    {
                        VoteCount = i.Votes.Sum(j => j.VoteValue),
                        Reply = i
                    })
                    .ToList();
```